# How to change styles of child component based on grid / list toggled in parent component, in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a view in Vue project.
Home.vue

```
<template>
    <TestLayout >
        <Card/>
        <Card/>
        <Card/>
    </TestLayout>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import TestLayout from "../components/TestLayout.vue"
  import Card from "../components/Card.vue"
  export default {
    name: "Home",
    props:{
      isList:{
        type: Boolean
      }
    },
  
    components: {
      TestLayout,
      Card
    },
  }
  </script>
```

The TestLayout has a section where we can display cards in list or grid view
TestLayout.vue

```
<template>
        <div class="flex border-solid ">
                    <ListBulletIcon class="h-10 w-10 cursor-pointer shadow border-2 border-indigo-600 rounded-l p-2"
                      @click="listView = true" />
                    <TableCellsIcon @click="listView = false"
                      class="h-10 w-10 cursor-pointer shadow border-2 border-indigo-600 rounded-r p-2" />
                  </div>
         <section
                    :class="[listView ? 'md:grid-cols-1 grid-cols-1' : 'md:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2', 'rounded-md grid  gap-5 col-span-full']">
                    <slot :listView="listView"></slot>
                  </section>
</template>
        <script>
    import {
      ListBulletIcon,TableCellsIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'
    
    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {
          listView: false,
        }
      },
      components: {
        ListBulletIcon,
        TableCellsIcon,
      },
      }
    }
    
    </script>
```

**I want to change the style of Card.vue based on whether user clicks grid view or list view icon.**

For example, I want to add this style to Card.vue div tag in its template:

```
:class="[isList ? 'dark:bg-midnight' : 'dark:bg-red-300', 'min-h-80 w-full bg-gray-50 shadow-xl rounded-md flex flex-col']"
```

How will I check isList is clicked or not?
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're half way there. After defining a slot prop (`<slot :listView="listView"></slot>`) you should access it in parent and pass it down to slot components.

```
<TestLayout>
  <template v-slot="{ listView }">
    <Card :isList="listView" />
    <Card :isList="listView" />
  </template>
</TestLayout>
```